# Windows FTP Server with granular permissions

Tags: permissions, ftp, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to create an FTP server that has granular permissions.  For example, I may have the following users:

admin
john
mark
dave
sarah

And want a structure such as:

/Shared (Read)
/Users/ (Read/Write for the user's folder only)
/Software (Read/Write)

How can I accomplish this?  I'm running Server 2008 R2 and don't see these options.

Comment: Would you look at a low cost third party app?

Comment: Potentially but I'd like to think that Windows or a free/open-source solution can accomplish this.

Comment: While I've never used it, it is very likely that the built-in FTP server respects the NTFS permissions on the disk.  You probably just need to set the right security permissions on the disk folders in question.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using the application CrushFTP for sveral years and it was inexpensive and very feature rich. Support is excellent and all users need is a web browser to upload or download. It supports secure transfers and has extensive reporting and alerting. Great features to protect against various attacks. It was easy to set up and users like all the features and security. Supports a number of platforms and uses few resourses.

Download a full demo at [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com)